# How to add ident to a block without reidenting it in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

If I had a typescript file idented by 4 spaces with some SQL strings idented with 2 spaces.

```
function ts_query(){
    const sql=`
      SELECT *
        FROM table1
        WHERE field1 IS NULL
          AND field2 IS NOT NULL
    `;
    return sql;
}
function other(x:string){
    if(x=="this"){
        return "that";
    }
}
```

When I select the SQL part and press tab the conent is reidented

[image: reident]

In the picture you can see that Visual Code is not respecting my original ident of that code section.

Is there a way to configure VisualStudioCode to do the same that Notepad++ does (i.e.: respecting the original format simply adding 4 spaces).

My settings.json is:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": false,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": false,
    "git.promptToSaveFilesBeforeCommit": true,
    "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "editor.autoIndent": false
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Code v1.28.2 in Windows 8.1

Comment: Open settings with Ctrl + comma, search Editor: Insert spaces settings, then check the box to enable.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Do you try it? It does not works. I try it right now.

Comment: I'm using it...... OK, there also other settings. 1. set `"editor.tabSize": 4` 2. enable `"editor.detectIndentation": true` 3. enable `"editor.autoIndent": true`.

Comment: After you press the tab key the word FROM still only 2 spaces righter than SELECT word?. In the original text FROM is 2 spaces rigther, then when I press tab the FROM word earns 2 more spaces.

Comment: Oooo... That one. It maybe by-design issue.Notepad++ and VSCode uses different modules for syntax.